# autoptimize showing error 404 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I used this plugin called *Autoptimize* to optimize js and css everything was working fine. But then I updated the theme and after that still it was working but suddenly it started showing error in console, it shows an error stating 404 not found. But I am not using this plugin anymore it still shows the error of autoptimize(Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)). Tried to find the solution not able to find. The website loads properly on but not on desktop Need serious help.

Comment: Did you uninstall the plugin the proper way?

Comment: @Adam Yeah, I have installed it in a proper way. But again deleted it by seeing the error in console.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a number of steps to debug and solve the issue:

- Check if the plugin got uninstalled properly, if you have SSH access or FTP check that it's not on

> wp-content/plugins/autoptimize

- Check that the content you're getting on the browser is not being cached by another plugin/service eg. cloudflare or something, do a hard reset of browser cache

[How to do a hard reload on chrome](http://www.code-pal.com/quick-tip-clear-cache-hard-refresh-on-chrome/)

- Check if the .htaccess is ok, most caching plugins change and add rules on the main .htaccess, the basic and default should be like this:
  [Basic WP .htaccess](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess#Basic_WP) if it looks different than that, ssh/ftp edit it to match that
- Flush the permalinks on WordPress admin: [Flushing Permalinks in WordPress](https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/)

If none of the above works be more specific and input console information on what resource is not being found, good luck.

Comment: The website loads perfectly on a mobile device. Problem is only with laptop or desktop. In the console, I see it is searching for some image which is not present in the media library and some js file with autoptimize, not present. Another interesting thing is that is if I create a replica of the page it loads perfectly fine. But when I link it to be the front page of the website i.e the home page it shows error.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem with error 404. Exactly on server I hadn't js file. In console found the error "bwg_main_ready is not defined". The way which resolved my problem:

1. Go to Autoptimizer widget's settings.
2. In first box: Javascript options, turn off checkbox: Optimize JavaScript code?
3. Go to page where You have error and reload page.
4. On reloded page: "Tools for developers" - "Elements" - check in HTML's code if still exist script tag to non-existent autoptimizer js file, f.e. defer="" src="https://www.your_page.com/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/js/autoptimize_143457cf5as3cds55cc8d81712c1adsa.js
5. If not exists, return to Autoptimizer widget's settings and turn on checkbox: Optimize JavaScript code?

I hope this solution helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your browser (or your server/wordpress) may have some pages stuck in the cache.

Try purging your browser's page cache, as well as any WordPress caches you can find.

Comment: @bob I tried clearing the cache through plugins as well as cleared the browser cache. Replica of the page works perfectly fine. But when I link it to exact page it shows error.